# FGLS Correcting Serial Correlation and heteroskedasticity with plm package in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, plm

I am running a regression model with some heteroskedasticity and serial correlation and I am trying to solve both without changing my model specification.

First, I have generated an OLS model and realized both problems, heteroskedasticity and serial correlation. So, I tried to run a feasible generalized least square (FGLS) model with plm's `pggls` command to solve both problems at the same time, but this command seems to only solve heteroskedasticity and not serial correlation.

My code is as follows:

```
base<-pdata.frame(base, index = c("ID","time"), drop = FALSE)
Reg<-pggls(sells~ prices + income + stock+
           period1 + period2+ period3, model = c("pooling"), 
           data=base)
```

This command seems to correct heteroskedasticity, but it certainly does not correct for serial correlation as I created a simple proof. Below I generated a regression between the residuals and the lagged residuals of the regression model:

```
res = Reg$res 
n = length(res)
mod = lm(res[-n] ~ res[-1]) 
summary(mod)
```

The `res[-1]` coefficient is mod is significative. So it has not solved the serial correlation.

Does somebody know how to add some option to the `pggls` command to solve this?, or does somebody know a better command for solving both problems? It does not necessarily need to be a panel data command as I only have 1 individual.

Comment: `lm(res[-n] ~ res[-1])` will not give you what you want, use `plm::lag` instead.

Comment: Just do an OLS regression and use robust (heteroskedasticity and serial correlation robust) standard errors, look at package `sandwich`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you said you don't need a panel structure you could correct the standard errors directly, which is the more used appraoch in econometrics literature. In fact, GLS estimation is a bit old fashioned today...

You could do:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

reg <-lm(sells ~ prices + income + stock + period1 + period2+ period3, data = base)

coeftest(reg, vcov = vcovHAC(reg))
```

Just for completness, if you'd like to produce a clustered robust estimation like Stata does, you cloud try Tarzan's `cl` function from [here](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/heteroskedasticity-robust-and-clustered-standard-errors-in-r/).

Comment: the functions `vcovXX` (e.g. `vcovHC`) in package `plm` should do the clustered SE as well - easier than to implement it yourself.